# Nested for loops iteration alternatives

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have the following different types

```
Types:
R -> R1, R2, R3....
RE -> RE1, RE2, RE3....
REA -> REA1, REA2, REA3...

They have the following relationship.
```

[image: Tree Structure]

For a given list of items i want to iterate over each leaf and perform some actions.
Right now, i have a for loop nested three levels.

```
for (r in Rs) {
 List<RE> REs = get(R);
 for(re in REs) {
   List<REA> REAs = get(re);
   for(rea in REAs) {
     //do some processing for the list of items
     for(each item in items) {
       //process each item
     }
   }
 }
}
```

is there a better approach to this iterative one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which language do you use, but you could shorten that snippet by not storing all the lists in locals:

```
for (r in Rs) {
  for (re in get(r)) {
    for (rea in get(re)) {
      for (item in rea) {
        //process each item
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can go recursive:

```
traverse(items) {
    if (items.isLeaf()) {
      // process items
    } else {
        for (item in items) {
            traverse(item);
        }
    }
}
traverse(Rs)
```

Comment: so i should be building a Tree structure to begin with? right now i have stored them in maps and lists.

Comment: @Bharath maps and lists is already a tree structure. You can traverse them.